# Simple Photo Management Android Application

Tags: android, file-management, photography, image-viewer, gallery

I am looking for an android photo management application that does the following:

- Ability to store text or tags associated with that photo file (not text *on* the photo)
- Sorting by date / tags
- Simple to use (older audiences in mind)
- Local photo management similar to Picasa (view and inspect photos stored on the device, individually or by albums)

Not as important:

- Photo editing capabilities
- Sharing abilities
- Offline functionality

I have tried out a few different applications. [Picasa](http://picasa.google.ca/) was the closest to what I was looking for but it did not have the ability to store text with the photo. My current hack is having the photos on dropbox, but still, this doesn't give me the ability to store text with them. The built in story book app on the Galaxy Tab 10.1 also falls short.

Comment: related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/android-app-for-quickly-tagging-grouping-photos-by-drag-click

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know what's "similar to Picasa", as I don't use Picasa. But for everything else, **[Monte Gallery](http://www.appbrain.com/app/kr.co.itfs.gallery.droid)** should be a good match.

[image: Monte 1] [image: Monte Calendar] [image: Monte Map]
<sup>*Monte Gallery:* Folder, Calendar, and Map view (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

As above screenshots show, you can browse by folders or calendar (your "date" requirement). You even can browse by location (list not shown in screenshots), and have your photos shown on the map. Here comes a little "pitfall", though, as "by location" always goes down to street-level, and there's no possibility to group by any larger scale like "country". But as location-browsing was not listed with your requirements, I suppose you can live with that :)

*Monte* also supports tagging, and you can list your pictures by tags. But not only that:

[image: Monte Memo] [image: Monte Voice-Memo] [image: Monte Safe]
<sup>*Monte Gallery:* Text / voice memos, image vault (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

You can add text or voice memos to your images, or put sensitive once in a "safe". The app also features the calendar as widget (I never used that, though), and of course you can create albums (didn't try that either).

From your "bonus features", sharing is supported by the app. But is has no editing features.

I'd say the app is easy and intuitive to use. On the device where I use it, it sometimes takes a while until new pictures show up, and there's the "location sort" thing. But the former might well be device- or Android-version specific, and the latter won't affect you – so it should definitely be worth a try.

Oh, one minor thing, though: there is no gratis version available on Google Play. But the paid version is less than US$1.50, so it shouldn't hurt *that* much.

Comment: Are the iptc-tag infos read-from/stored-to the jpg file so that when copying the tagged-jpg to the pc the tag info is there?

Comment: @k3b Looks like Monte just stores them to its own SQLite database, which made its comment function pretty much useless for me. For that fact and that it's no longer updated, I hardly use it anymore. I've not yet tested a good replacement for me, but you might take a look at [FastPhotoTagger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.fastphototagger), which claims to use "ExifTool to read & write metadata" (thus they should end up within the files). Please ping me if it matches, be welcome to write a question and answer it yourself and I'll upvote it :)

Comment: as i found out there is a "microsoft-exif-standard" to store image tags, image title, image description and image ratings which seems to be suported by many photo apps (exiftools, digikam) so today iptc metadata support is not a must have any more

Comment: @k3b I didn't know that [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) is an MS product. Wikipedia lists different companies behind it, with MS not even in the list. Apart from that: Yes, Exif is widely spread and supported – seems even more than IPTC.

Comment: microsoft has just added a few tags to the standard exif using some exif ids-s that where not assigned yet.

Comment: @k3b Ah, that's cool! So APhotoManager will have Exif edit soon, and store data directly in the image files? Didn't know it was you, but I already had your app on my list to investigate, so thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

**[AndroFotoFinder](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki)** has

- ability to store tags associated with that photo file in the jpg file
- Sorting by date / tags

But it is not so simple to use because it does not use the album=folder metaphor.

Instead it can search photos by tag(s), date-range, gps-data, folder, filename... which makes it powerful but more difficult to use.

It is

- free, open source, no adds, no user tracking
- available on [f-droid.org app store](https://f-droid.org/app/de.k3b.android.androFotoFinder), but not on play store